# How to make a text readable by a text to speech in a j2me application

Tags: java-me, text-to-speech, midlet

I'm writing a midlet that write some lines of text on the screen.

my problem is that using a StringItem, the TTS reads just the last line on the screent

Comment: TTS interesting. _just one line_ could you elaborate here? did you use line breaks or it was auto-wrapped? Also, did you try other objects besides `StringItem`? `TextBox` or maybe `Alert` for example?